# Binding ASP.Net Web.Config Settings To .ASPX File <a href></a>?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, app-config

#### The Scenario

I have an ASP.NET web project. I want to be able to define all of the links for the site inside my web.config file so that they can be changed easily if needs be. Currently I have an "" section in my web.config file.

#### The Question

How do I bind this key value pair to an '' tag in my .aspx file?!

#### The App Settings in My Web.Config File

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="MyNewLink" value="http://someurl.co.uk/" />
</appSettings>
```

Help greatly appreciated.

#### EDIT:

Sorry I should have mentioned that this is for a html link: `**<a href></a>**`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your aspx file it would be:

```
NavigateUrl='<%$ AppSettings:MyNewLink %>'
```

and the full <a> tag is defined as:

```
<a runat="server" href="<%$ AppSettings:MyNewLink %>">Text link</a>
```

This syntax can only be used on an ASP.NET WebForms server control.

Comment: This fails......

###Error Message:

Literal expressions like '<%$ AppSettings:MyNewLink %>' are not allowed. Use <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ AppSettings:MyNewLink%>" /> instead.

Comment: This definitely works:
<a runat="server" href="<%$ AppSettings:MyNewLink %>">Text link</a>

Comment: Well you learn something new every day, I didn't know you could do that!  Thanks @Locksfree

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this what a .sitemap file is for?

Anyway, as far as I know, you will have to 'bind' this from code behind.  Something like:

```
hlYourLink.NavigateUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyNewLink"];
```

Comment: so i would have to give the <a href=""></a> an ID attribute called 'h1YourLink'?

Comment: And a runat="server" .. But the above solution Locksfree provided should work.

Comment: Oh, and you should use the asp:hyperlink control, because the a tag doesn't have a property called navigateurl

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this......

#### .aspx file

```
<asp:literal id="litgetquote" runat="server"></asp:literal>
```

#### .aspx.cs CODE BEHIND

```
litgetquote.Text = "<A HREF='" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GetQuoteUrl"] + "'>" +
            "get a quote now" + "</A>";
```

Comment: you should consider using this for readability:
litgetquote.Text = string.Format("<A HREF='{0}'>get a quote now</A>", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GetQuoteUrl"]);

Comment: I believe all you needed was runat='server' in your <a> element.