# How to access web.config settings directly in .aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I've created a web page and it contains some settings value in Web.Config for example images. So I want to give the path of images in Web.Config file and file name in that particular image src.

I wanted to read that settings only in aspx page not in codebehind.

For example

Below is my code:

```
Web.Config:
<add key="ImagePath" value="http://192.168.0.181/Labeling/Images/"/>
```

and in my aspx page,

```
<img id="ImgHeader" runat="server" src="<%ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagePath"]%>" />
```

Comment: below answers are correct, but you should also think about creating a user control (with just the image tag/inline code), to avoid magic strings in all the affected ASPX/ASCX's.

Comment: <%$ AppSettings:ImagePath %>

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559446/binding-asp-net-web-config-settings-to-aspx-file-a-href-a

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
<img id="ImgHeader" runat="server" src="<%$ ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ImagePath"] %>" />
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Error: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

Comment: You should use ConfigurationManager instead of ConfigurationSettings (now obsolete) unless you are using .Net 2 or less.

Comment: Use single quotes if you're still getting the Server tags error. 
src='<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagePath"] %>' />

Answer (score 16):

Waqas Iqbal's answer:

```
<%$ AppSettings:ImagePath %>
```

Eg:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ AppSettings:ImagePath %>
```

from [Binding ASP.Net Web.Config Settings To .ASPX File <a href></a>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559446/binding-asp-net-web-config-settings-to-aspx-file-a-href-a) worked nicely!

Answer (score 7):

```
<%= ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ImagePath"] %>
```

Comment: Parser Error Message: Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

Source Error: 


Line 234:                        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" /></td>
Line 235:                    <td>
Line 236:                        <asp:Button ID="btnDisplay" Text="Display Page" runat="server" OnClientClick="window.open('<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HtmlOutputPath"] %>')" /></td>
Line 237:                </tr>
Line 238:            </table>

Comment: Note: You can get this error if your page is set for VisualBasic instead of C#. In that case, change the square brackets to round brackets (parentheses). Example: '<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("HtmlOutputPath") %>'

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ImagePath") %>
```

Comment: ConfigurationManager and brackets is what worked for me.... <%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagePath"] %>