# How to read web.config settings in .aspx page (<asp:Label..)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

My question is just similar to this question [How to read web.config settings in .aspx page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4152842/1134935)

Just a modification is that I want the label text in ASPX page as such:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblmyLabel" runat="server" Text="<%$ ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MyLabel"]%>"></asp:Label>
```

But it give me the error "Cannot resolve the symbol (lblmyLabel)"

How to achieve this task?

Comment: why don't you add from .cs file?

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
<asp:Label ID="lblmyLabel" runat="server" Text="<%$appSettings:MyLabel %>"></asp:Label>
```