# Get Settings value in .aspx page?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, xml

Is it possible to get Settings value in .aspx page?

My settings in web.config looks like this:

```
<applicationSettings>
<School.Properties.Settings>
    <setting name="StudentUrl" serializeAs="String">
     <value>http://www.studentUrl.com</value>
   </setting>
</School.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

My aspx page looks like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkSchoolUrl" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl="">Click for Student URL</asp:HyperLink>
```

How to get my 'StudentUrl' value from Web.config in hyperlink in aspx page?

Comment: Did you try using the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. but i decided to go with this solution:
[Binding ASP.Net Web.Config Settings To .ASPX File <a href></a>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559446/binding-asp-net-web-config-settings-to-aspx-file-a-href-a)

Answer (score 0):

In your code behind, try this:

```
School.Properties.Settings settings = new School.Properties.Settings();
String StudentUrl = settings.StudentUrl;
```